# Autoregressive Models for Multivariate Time Series in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, time-series, arima, autoregressive-models

I am new to Spark. I want to implement vector autoregressive models for multivariate time series, and the most important that i want to implement ARIMA but i don't know if this is possible with Spark/Scala as long as the algorithm should be parallalyzed to run on the cluster.

My question is : is it possible to work with vector autoregressive models for multivariate time series in Spark?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is already an implementation of ARIMA in Spark https://github.com/sryza/spark-timeseries/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/cloudera/sparkts/models/ARIMA.scala However there is no public implementation of multivariate vector autoregression (just univariate). I implemented multivariate vector autoregression in Spark, unfortunately I can't make it public as it belongs to the enterprise where I currently work...

Comment: can you give an idea in pm, please

Comment: It's complicated to give a detailed idea. What I did is to fully understand the implementation of vector autoregression in R. Once you have done this, you might find useful the following libraries: https://github.com/sryza/spark-timeseries/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/cloudera/sparkts/MatrixUtil.scala , https://github.com/sryza/spark-timeseries/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/cloudera/sparkts/Lag.scala and especially https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/wiki/Linear-Algebra-Cheat-Sheet